# Question on Aarch64 assembly address formats

Tags: assembly, arm64, addressing-mode

I am new to linux GDB, and I have a questions on Aarch64 assembly:

On my assembler dump, there are the following lines:

`0x0000005555555788 <+36>:    str     w0, [sp, #24]`

`0x000000555555578c <+40>:    ldr     w1, [sp, #24]`

I know what LDR and STR means, and that w0, w1 represents registers,

But I would like to know the `[sp, #24]` part. What does `sp` and `#24` mean?

Comment: It's an addressing mode involving SP, the stack pointer.  Read the vendor-supplied manual or any tutorial for the basics, e.g. this one on arm.com: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101/Loads-and-stores---addressing covers AArch64 addressing-modes.     See also [ARM AArch64 stack management](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31346886) and [understanding aarch64 assembly function call, how is stack operated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66098678), although neither of those are duplicates.

Comment: @PeterCordes The ARM documentation helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`str w0, [sp, #24]` means "store `w0` at the address `sp+24`".

`ldr w1, [sp, #24]` means "load `w1` from the address `sp+24`".

These are both using the "base plus offset" syntax explained in section C1.3.3 of the [Architecture Reference Manual](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/60119835773bb020e3de6fee).